# Get an rvalue when calling a getter method on an rvalue object

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Suppose, I have the following code. There's a copy constructor in B which calls a method which copies the resources of a.

Now I also have a move constructor. In this case, a should not be copied but just "steal" the resources from an existing a. Therefore, I also implemented an init taking an rvalue. But of course, when I try to call it with parameter b.a, this is an lvalue...

Is there a way to call this method?

```
class A{

    A(const A&& a){
        // 'steal' resources from a
    }

    void init(A& a){
       // init this A from another A by copying its resources
    }

    void init(A&& a){
      // init this A from another A stealing its resources and tell the other a, it must not destroy resources upon destruction
    }
};

class B{
    A a;

    B(B& b){
      a.init(b.a)          
    }

    B(B&& b){
      a.init(b.a); // How to call init(A&& a)?  
    }

};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`b.a` is an lvalue, so you need to apply `std::move`:

```
a.init(std::move(b.a));
```

---

**Note**: *But why is `b` an lvalue in the body of `B(B&& b)`?*

Here, the parameter type `B&& b` simply means that this constructor overload will be chosen over, say, `B(const B& b)` when invoked with an rvalue.

```
B make_B() { return B(); }
B b1(make_B());            // B(B&&) chosen
B b2(b);                   // B(const B&) chosen
```

But the parameter itself is an lvalue because it has a name. All `std::move` does is make its argument look like an rvalue.

Comment: How is `b.a` an lvalue?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `b` is an lvalue, `a` is the name of its data member, so `b.a` is an lvalue.

Comment: Okay, so how is `b` an lvalue?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It has a name.

Comment: Thanks! You should put that in your answer as the OP most likely made the assumption the `b` is an rvalue too.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused now.. b in B(B&& b) is an rvalue I think? And: Are names of data members (rvalue.member) of rvalues also rvalues?

Comment: @Michael `b` is a reference to an rvalue but since it has a name it is treated as an lvalue. `std::move()` is a way to cast that object back into an rvalue (technically xvalue).

Comment: @0x499602D2 I added a short explanation.